# Javascript make an image bounce around screen

Tags: javascript

I have made code for a bouncing ball (using the arc() method on a canvas). I am wondering how to make an image bounce around the screen. Here is my previous code (note that the launchBall() function is going to be the function that runs the bouncing image):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>  

<body onload="startBall()" oncontextmenu="return false;" style="cursor: none; overflow: hidden;">
    <center>

    <div id="div" style="width: 1600px; height: 700px; border: 2px solid #000000; background-color: grey;">

    <br>
    <img draggable="false"id="image" style="position: absolute;" width="50" height="50"src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/b/a/b/0/1207156679935151925noxin_crosshairs.svg.hi.png"/>

    </div>
    <center>
    <p>Score: <a>0</a></p>
    </center>

    <script>
        var dx = 3;
        var dy = 3;
        var x = 100;
        var y = 100;
        var radius = 20;

        var interval;

        function startBall(){
            interval = setInterval(launchBall, 20);
        }

        function launchBall(){
            var c = document.getElementById("canvas");
            var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 1275, 695);
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(x, y, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
            ctx.fillStyle = "red";
            ctx.fill(); 
            document.getElementById
            if(x<20 || x>1255) dx=-dx;
            if(y<20 || y>675) dy=-dy;
            x = x + dx;
            y = y + dy; 
        }

    document.getElementById("div").onmousemove = function(e) {
        document.getElementById("image").style.top = e.pageY -25 + "px";
        document.getElementById("image").style.left = e.pageX -25 +"px";
    }
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `var c = document.getElementById("canvas");` what canvas?

Comment: That was just earlier code I have just been too lazy to delete :)